# "Was kostet" oder "Wie kostet"?

Tags: difference

Translate directly from English, I write:

> Wie kostet ist es ?

But my friend said that it should be:

> Was kostet ist er ?

So which one is correct?
Thanks!

Comment: Both sentences are wrong. We need a bit more context - what are you trying to translate?

Comment: @Hulk I'd say the first sentence  is a word by word translation of _How much is it?_ .

Comment: "Wie **teuer** ist es?" or "Wie viel **kostet** es?" are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wie kostet **ist** er?
>
> Was kostet **ist** er?

Both sentences are **wrong**. The word "*kosten*" is already a verb so no "*ist*" is allowed anymore.

"*Wie kostet*..." would be: "How does it cost?", not "How *much* does it cost?"

The correct sentences are:

> Wie **viel** kostet er?
>
> Was kostet er?

In normal language, both sentences have absolutely the same meaning. Both variants are in use.

If you **take it literally** (**no** native speaker does) there is the following difference between "**was** kostet" and "**wie viel** kostet":

Think about the following sentence: "This project had a very high price: Two people are dead, the environment is polluted and there were costs of one billion dollars."

"**Was** kostet er?" means that you want to have information about which kinds of costs are expected (deaths? pollution? money?) and of course the amount of these costs.

"**Wie viel** kostet er?", however, implies that you already know about the kinds of costs (you know it only costs money) and you are only interested in the amount.

---

By the way:

Asking for a price using "*er*" or "*sie*" sounds a bit strange for me. After a bit of thinking I found out why:

In the dialect spoken in the region where I live it is common not to use the pronouns "er/sie/es" but to use the article ("der/die/das") of the noun:

> Sie haben ein schönes Kleid. Wo kann man **das** kaufen?

I don't know if this is allowed in "official" German language or only done in the dialect spoken here.

However when asking for a **total amount** or for a **price indication** people here often say:

> Wie viel kostet **es**?

When asking for a certain product people here in this region would however say:

> Wie viel kostet **das**?

Comment: Whether you use *es*, *er* or *sie* depends on the context, that is, the grammatical gender of the thing you want to buy, e.g. "Ich möchte dieses Auto kaufen. Was kostet es?" / "Ich möchte diesen Stuhl kaufen. Was kostet er?"/ "Ich möchte diese Vase kaufen. Was kostet sie?"

Comment: @RHa I edited my answer.